# Refreshing current tab contents in response to an event common to all tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, event-handling

I have a time slider that is common to all tabs in a page.
Content of each tab is loaded in a div element.
I have listeners for each of the tab's js that listen to events/changes in time slider.
If I now move the time slider, all the tabs on the page get refreshed.
However, I want only the current tab's content to get refreshed.

### tab1.js

```
timesliderlistener(){
refreshtab1contents();
}
```

### tab2.js

```
timesliderlistener(){
refreshtab2contents();
}
```

As the timeslider is common to both tabs, both listeners are invoked when it is moved. If I check for current tab before refreshing; I lose the event for the next tab. How do I save the event, so that refresh of the other tab also happens when I click on it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass Id/name of the tab to listener and check whether it is current tab, if yes then and only then refresh the content in the tab.